# Is it possible to read logs in CLI when running Ionic app on Physical Android Device

Tags: android, cordova, logging, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an Android app using Ionic framework. I'm able to see the logs generated in the browser. But is there any way to get the logs in CLI when running the app in Android physical device instead of an emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your device with the USB cable. In Cli run command `adb logcat`

Comment: http://help.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/How-to-Collect-Logs-via-Command-Line-ADB-on-Android-Devices

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to see the same logs (as you would when in the browser) when running the app on the actual device by running the app with ionic like this:

```
ionic run android -l -c
```

`-l` switch is for livereaload

`-c` switch is for console logs

Comment: This gave me an error saying "The connection to server failed"